# Is there a way to set the actual size of an external display for extending the desktop?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a Surface Pro 4 with a screen size of ~12 inches diagonal and a resolution of 2736x1824, and I'm using it with an external monitor that's about 18 inches but has a much lower resolution (1680x1050). I have the scaling at 200% on the Surface Pro screen and 100% on the monitor, which is good for the size of text and stuff.

But for extending the desktop, Windows thinks the monitor is much smaller than the Pro screen since its resolution is lower. This means that moving the mouse between screens is totally thrown off, and it's impossible to line the monitors up in the display settings to reflect how they are in reality.

[Windows setting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxllF.png); [actual display sizes and arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODuVc.jpg)

Does anyone know of a way to fix this issue? I know it can't be fixed through Windows settings, but I was hoping there's some utility out there that can, or some other creative solutions.

Comment: Fix what exactly? When you have screens of different resolutions, you will end up with those unmatched edges you bump into.  Unfortunately the physical size of the monitors means nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 monitors - different resolutions - cursor between monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/775255/2-monitors-different-resolutions-cursor-between-monitors), [Dual Monitor Display - Cursor hitting “border” between monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/29552/dual-monitor-display-cursor-hitting-border-between-monitors?rq=1), etc.

Comment: And [Monitors with different pixel sizes](http://superuser.com/questions/333556/monitors-with-different-pixel-sizes)

Comment: Fix the unmatched edges so the mouse moves seamlessly between the monitors, taking into account their physical size. Yes, those are essentially the same question as mine (and [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/1066680/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-in-windows-with-a-multiple-monitor-setup-behave-like-i)), but there are no actual solutions in the answers.

Comment: I actually tried that solution and it's the closest thing to what I'm looking for that I've found so far, but it doesn't fix the actual issue, it only makes one of the symptoms a little less annoying.

Comment: Ok, then back to my original question.  Fix what exactly?   Aside from snagging unaligned edges, what "issues" are you trying to resolve?

Comment: The snagging edges and the fact that the pointer doesn't go to the closest (physical) location on the other monitor when moving it across the border. (Which can't be fixed by adjusting the monitor positions in the Windows display settings, because Windows doesn't know the true physical size, just infers it from the resolution.)